# How do I transform this curl request with javascript axios

Tags: javascript, curl, axios, google-speech-api

I want to perform a request to the Google speech API, to return the translation of audio I sent to the API

If I use the curl command below, I successfully retrieve the data, but I don't know how to pass it to an Axios request.

**curl command:**

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/{speech_name}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // creating axios 
 const api = axios.create({
 baseURL: https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations,
 crossDomain: true,
 responseType: 'json',
 headers: {
 'Accept': 'application/json',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'Authorization':'your_key
 },
});

// calling api

api.get('/speech_name')
.then(res=>{
console.log(res);
}).
catch('error');
```

Note : you can use other request method also `api.post(url)`